# Entity Framework model issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having some strange issues, I am attempting to pull a record out of the database and it seems like most of it is `null` even know if I manually look in the DB it's populated.

**Model**

```
public class AdminConfiguration : Entity // Entity is an abstract class containing an ID
{
    public bool Authentication { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationConfiguration> ApplicationConfiguration { get; set; }
    public List<LinksConfiguration> LinksConfiguration { get; set; }
    public EmailConfiguration EmailConfiguration { get; set; }
    public bool WakeOnLan { get; set; }
}
```

Basically any reference to another class is `null` The only thing that is populated is the `WakeOnLan` property.

**Query**

```
    public AdminConfiguration Find(int id)
    {
        return Db.AdminConfiguration.Find(id);
    }
```

I have a feeling I have a misunderstanding regarding how I set up the models. I am expecting the query to return me a fully populated `AdminConfiguration` object.

Comment: @DanielA.White what does that mean?

Comment: entity framework won't load anything unless you need it.

Comment: @DanielA.White so if I wanted the whole object what would I have to do?

Comment: look around on here - there are plenty of questions concerning lazy loading in entity framework.

Comment: Do a .Includes before the .Find. Ex .include("propertyname") or .include(x=>x.EmailConfiguration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set navigation properties as virtual to enable lazy loading:

```
public virtual List<ApplicationConfiguration> ApplicationConfiguration { get; set; }
```

Please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx

> This enables the Lazy Loading feature of Entity Framework. Lazy
>   Loading means that the contents of these properties will be
>   automatically loaded from the database when you try to access them.

Comment: Lazy loading will only work if the context is still open so depending on where the property is accessed it may not solve this, the OP knows he needs something he should probably use an include

Answer (score 1):

The best way to setup your model is:

```
public class AdminConfiguration : Entity // Entity is an abstract class containing an ID
{
    public AdminConfiguration()
    {
        this.ApplicationConfigurations = new HashSet<ApplicationConfiguration>();
        this.LinksConfigurations = new HashSet<LinksConfiguration>();
    }
    public bool Authentication { get; set; }
    public EmailConfiguration EmailConfiguration { get; set; }
    public bool WakeOnLan { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationConfiguration> ApplicationConfigurations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LinksConfiguration> LinksConfigurations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The OP said he has misunderstanding regarding the model setup, so I thought it will be helpful for him to know the better way to setup models.

Comment: Also it enables lazy loading, which is what causing the values of navigation properties to be null.